# How to display HTTP content in HTTPS webpage

Tags: http, nginx, https, mixed-content

I have NGINX running in my server (HTTPS), and I have, also running in the server an API (via PM2). This API response is HTTP, and I want to display the responses in the HTTPS webpage.

I can't run the PM2 API in HTTPS. What I want is to allow HTTPS to serve HTTP content.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example_web.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example_api.com'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We can't fetch HTTP resources from HTTPS origin.
2. Most browsers block it for security reasons.
3. We can proxy the answer of the web service through your sever.